# How can generate a insert statement having now() method in value using a procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have written a procedure that generate insert statements in an output file, in the generated insert statement there is a creation_date field. 
In the procedure , when  giving `now()` in values it is putting current time stamp in generated insert statement. When giving `now()` (in single codes) in values it is putting `now()` as a varchar in generated insert statement.
I require , `now()` will be printed in generated insert statement so that when insert statement is executed that current timestamp will be stored in database.

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO table_name(col1,col2, creation_date) values(...,now()) as output_dml 
INTO OUTFILE 'url+file_name' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
from  another_table_name.
```

Please help me out.... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, creation_date) values (1, 1, \'', NOW(), '\') as output_dml
    INTO OUTFILE ', url, file_name, ' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'
    FROM another_table_name;');
```